# Object type does not match column type - Dashboard - Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm getting the `Object type does not match column type error` error for line 14 of my code, which is as follows:

```
var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(data).bind([nameFilter,issueFilter,hourFilter,dateFilter],[tableChart,pieChart]).build();
```

This question has been asked multiple times but I've tried the solution - making sure that all blank rows in any column are also formatted as the same data type - and it does not work.

Comment: Since you've seen the usual reason for this error, it's reasonable to expect that we'll need to know more about your situation to understand it. Please [edit] with more details. If you have a small data set that recreates the problem, sharing that would be ideal.